# I have a bike i wanna fix for my 2yr old grandson but have no ideas

Tags: children

I want to make a monsters inc bike for him

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for help with. We can definitely help with specific technical questions, but general ideas of how to develop your project aren't within the scope of this site. Is the bike mechanically sound? If not, what can we help you to fix? If you don't know, "How can I check if a child's bike is mechanically sound?" would be a great new question. Are you going to respray the frame? Maybe put stickers on it and put a layer of clear-coat on top? We can probably help with most of that.

Comment: Concur with David - what's your actual question?   This site is not a forum so vague open-ended questions are not a good fit.   If you're talking about customising the look, what's your end goal?  Something like this  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61L4lAs7NlL._SL1181_.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Remove the crank and the chain. If possible the rear sprocket or at least cover it with a decent layer of tape or a bit of cut open rubber hose. Lower the saddle so he can put his feet on the ground and teach him to balance

Comment: Good thinking - 2 years is a bit too young to be riding a 2 wheel bike, and a balance bike is perfect.   If OP has mechanical skills, then removing the BB completely and storing the parts for later might be wise.

Comment: @Criggie . the bike looks as if the crank is a one piece thing so removing the pedals and the crank would anyway imply a removal of the BB as well. Any decent LBS could do this in 10min. Cleaning the BB shell would probably take more time!

Comment: Please add "buy him a [certified](https://helmets.org/standard.htm) helmet that fits properly." Two-year-olds don't have the best balance and falling skills yet.

Answer (score 2):

As a suggestion...

If I were going to make a Monsters Inc. bike out of your bike I'd start by looking at the Monsters Inc. logo.

Here's a link to a search for [images of the logo](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=monsters%20inc%20logo&qs=n&form=QBIR&sp=-1&pq=monsters%20inc%20l&sc=8-14&sk=&cvid=F6C02516B98C439BAE69166CC7961D94).
Since it's blue letters with a white background and your bike is already blue, you could go with white letters and a blue background.

Remove all the stickers and decals so you have a plain blue and white bike.
- Some decals can be removed with tape. Apply sticky tape over the decal and pull it off.
- Some stickers come lose with soapy water.
- Some decals can be scraped off with a plastic card - an old credit card for example.

Then you would select the Monsters Inc logo (or logos) you want to put on the bike and Think about where it should go on the bike. It would be good to print logos off the web and cut them out. Then you could hold the logo on the bike to see how it would look and what size you need.

How you create your Monsters Inc stickers will depend on you skill set - or maybe you have a friend who can help.
- You could get some white sticker vinyl and cut out the logo by hand by tracing something you've printed off the web. The Monsters Inc logo is not too complicated.
- If you know someone with a vinyl cutter, like a Circut, they can program the machine to cut out a sticker for you.
- If you have a much steadier hand than I have maybe you can hand paint the logo on the bike.

It sounds like a great project!

Comment: Nice ideas - could also get a green helmet similar to Mike Wazowski and put one eyeball/mouth sticker on, and some blue/purple fur like James P Sullivan.   Note most 2 year olds won't spot inaccuracies so there's plenty of leeway.